# getGetFeatureInfoUrl Hit-detection tolerance

Tags: openlayers, wms, tiles, getfeatureinfo, qgis-server

I'm using [getGetFeatureInfoUrl](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.TileWMS.html#getGetFeatureInfoUrl) to retrieve features from a WMS layer like that:

```
var url = wmsSource.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
  evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857',
  {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/xml'}
);
```

I have the problem that the features are quite small and so it's difficult to select a feature.

Is there any workaround to add something like *hitTolerance* in [ol.interaction.Select](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.interaction.Select.html)? Or do I have to calculate manually an area and send a getGetFeatureInfoUrl request for every coordinate in this area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the server that you access happens to be GeoServer you can try to add a "buffer" parameter into your GetFeatureInfo request as documented in http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html.  Otherwise you can't alter the tolerance because it is a server side setting.

GetFeatureInfo request itself does not have any tolerance because it sends the exact x and y values of the clicked pixel. What happens on the server side depends on the server, some more info in mailing list thread http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/GetFeatureInfo-Buffer-tolerance-default-td5071320.html.

Comment: The map server is a QGIS server, but I didn't find any documentation about a buffer parameter. Do you know if there is one?

Comment: Read this http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/ogc_server_support.html#extra-parameters-supported-by-the-wms-getfeatureinfo-request

Comment: Thanks for the link. The FI_LINE_TOLERANCE parameter did the trick to add a hit tolerance on server side.